# how to read a file from a lift webapp

Tags: scala, web-applications, jetty, lift

I want to read xml file in my lift app:

> val data = XML.load(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(filename), encoding));

However, I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. where should I put the file, and what is the correct path from my scala code?

BTW - I am using embedded jetty for my testing, although I need a solution for dev env and production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be better solution for other paths but there is

```
var LiftRules.getResource : (String) ⇒ Box[URL]
```

or

```
def LiftRules.doWithResource(name: String)(f: (InputStream) ⇒ T): Box[T]
```

which usually point to files in `src/main/resources/`.

There is also

```
def LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml(name: String): Box[NodeSeq]
```

which may be the method you are looking for.

Comment: When I tried this methods I got MalformedUrlException. I couldn't understand if the file content or the resource path was not formed well.

Comment: Did you start the string with a slash (`/myresource.res`)?

Comment: It work: `LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml("/cities_hebrew_utf.xml");` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem in the general case, `new File("delme").createNewFile()` and see where it ends up.

Comment: This may change depending on the directory the server was started in.

Comment: Maybe, but for any particular configuration it will work, and it will work in Lift or Wicket or Play or...

Comment: It is working for me in my development environment. Hope it will work also when I will deploy it. Thanks!

Comment: I just say that so everyone is aware of this potential problem. It has caused us a lot of headaches when our database file suddenly disappeared just because the server had been started manually.