# Load a file a Lift boot?

Tags: scala, lift

I have a CSV file I want to load at boot of my Lift app, but I can't figure out where to place this file. I've tried putting it under src\main\resources and then using [LiftRules.getResource/doWithResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546887/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-lift-webapp), but no dice (I get a MalformedURLException).

What's the standard way to do this in Lift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered on the Lift mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/f916080a716021a6). Turns out that sbt does not copy resources over when issuing compile or container:start commands, but only when executing the package command. This may be an sbt bug.